# Values From Cloud Firestore Duplicates During Sum Operation

Tags: java, android, firebase, math, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to android developement and I want to create android calorie calculator app, calories of food are stored inside cloud firestore. This  calorie counter is made of 5 value (breakfast,lunch,dinner,consumed_calories,and daily goal). After Calories are assigned to meal, I want to sum them into variable "consumed calories" which is the sum of 3 meals (breakfast,lunch and dinner). Daily Goal is (Daily Goal - Consumed Calories).
When I add one food eg. apple = 52 kcals, everything works fine, but when I add one more apple Daily Goal is = Daily Goal - 156 instead of 104, It takes value from inserted food and sum it with choosen calories.

[image]

My Code For Food Insert:

```
 public void MealCalories(DocumentReference reference, int calories, TextView textView, String Meal) {
    reference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            int meal = documentSnapshot.getLong(Meal).intValue();
            meal = meal + calories;
            AddData(Meal, meal, reference);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(meal));


            ConsumedCalories(calories);


        }
    });
}

public void ConsumedCalories(int calories) {
    MealRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


            int breakfast = documentSnapshot.getLong("Breakfast: " + uid).intValue();
            int lunch = documentSnapshot.getLong("Lunch: " + uid).intValue();
            int dinner = documentSnapshot.getLong("Dinner: " + uid).intValue();
            int consumed = documentSnapshot.getLong("Consumed Calories: " +uid).intValue();


                consumed = breakfast + lunch + dinner ;


            MealRef.update("Consumed Calories: " + uid, consumed);
            daily_goal.setText(String.valueOf(consumed));

            int daily_calories = documentSnapshot.getLong("Daily Goal: " + uid).intValue();

            daily_calories = daily_calories - consumed;

            MealRef.update("Daily Goal: "+ uid,daily_calories);

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Daily Goal was supposed to be 1896.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo First I wanna say thank you for your fast response, I put some pictures of my app. In the first picture we can see that the daily goal is 1948, and Consumed Calories are 52 when I add apple again I have 104 in Consumed Calories but 1844 in Daily Goal, daily goal was supposed to be 1896, but app somehow takes value from inserted calories, e.g I put apple which is 52 calories inside my app, if I put it once more inside my app, daily calories won't be (Daily Calories - 104, but Daily Calories - 156. I think the problem is in this line of code :  consumed = breakfast + lunch + dinner ;

Comment: Double counting happens in this line ` daily_calories = daily_calories - consumed;`. Each update you subtract cumulative consumption for this day. I think it should be something like this ` daily_calories = daily_calories - calories;`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code is fetching the consumed value from the snapshot, and then immediately overwriting it:

```
int consumed = documentSnapshot.getLong("Consumed Calories: " +uid).intValue();
consumed = breakfast + lunch + dinner ;
```

Is this intentional? Should it be consume += breakfast ... etc?